# Developer in-app payment - Google Wallet - jsontoken

Tags: eclipse, maven, android-pay

Has anyone been able to use Google Wallet in-app payment in an app or is it PayPal that I should use?

How to build pom.xml om mac?

Download jsontoken: https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/docs/tutorial#2

What I have tried is:

A:

1. "mvn pom.xml" gives me plugin errors.
2. Building the plugin from:
   http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/plugins/trunk/maven-jar-plugin/

Gives me errors

B:

Import the pom into Eclipse: This gives me errors like:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (execution: enforce-maven, phase: validate) pom.xml /jsontoken  line 18 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I've built the JsonToken library you can find it at the link below.  Also working on creating an Uber Jar containing all of the dependencies as well

http://db.tt/m4p32ZcH